# MSSQL - Uniquely identify an application connecting SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, session

we are implementing a database firewall on Oracle based on a unique value associated to a given application. With this value, we can reliably identify the application, even if one changes the name of the application before connecting to the RDBMS.

We plan on doing the same thing with SQL Server.

I've already seen that there is a `connection_id` column in `sys.dm_exec_connections`, but it identifies a connection, not an application.

In SQL Server, iIs there something, that could reliably identify an application ?

Comment: Did you look at sys.dm_exec_sessions?

Comment: Can you share how you accomplished this in Oracle? AFAIK, this would need to be done at the application layer.

Comment: +1 to @DanGuzman - This would need to be implemented at the application level. There is nothing stopping me from taking the same application and spoofing a whole bunch of fake data about it while connecting.

Comment: Better alternative in SQL Server would be to use AD groups based permissions and having each application use unique group/service account, and then it becomes an administrative job, not a coding job of creating a solution for every possible combination. No matter what DB engine it is, if different applications with same name connect with same connection string running under the same service account, you will never know the difference.

Comment: @DanGuzman, @SeanGallardy
We are currently implementing. In Oracle, there is a "module_hash" column in v$session that is different from application to application. So, if you have a MyApp.exe running with a given module hash and you take excel.exe and rename to to MyApp.exe => the `module_hash` value will differ.

Well, I know the better way is to use separate logins for separate duties. But there are so many applications that don't meet this by design (we always buy applications where I work - a hospital-, so these changes cannot be made that easily)

Comment: @ScottHodgin
Thanks, but I've not found what I need in sys.dm_exec_sessions neither.

Answer (score 1):

The only way I can think of is, using "Application Name" in the connection string.
That is how SQL server recognises different applications.

I think, you can append application name in the connection string at runtime using your v$session column.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what you need, the basic data for conenctions can all be found in `sys.sysprocesses` table

Main points of reference are

- ***spid*** (the database's connection identification number)
- ***hostmane*** (the machine from which the process is connecting (no hostname means an internal system)
- ***program_name*** (This will show what the program identifies itself as, for things like SSMS its useful, if you're using developed software this can be set and is most likely what you're after.) NOTE this is down to the application identifying itself so may need to be taken with a pinch of salt
- ***loginame*** (The user under which the connection is logged in as, if you're system is set up with security heavily in mind, each user will have one task that it can perform and can identify which application is running the connection through that). NOTE: This is reliant on your access being secure and your devs not re-using logins.
- ***hostprocess*** (If you know the hostname and hostprocess and can connect to the machine running that application you can use a program such as taskmanager to see what program on that machine has that hostprocess ID and work out what application is operating that connection that way (this is long winded but accurate)

All of these can be used in conjunction with each other to help paint a better picture of what is actually connecting to an instance

`sp_who` or `sp_who2` will give you these metrics apart from the `hostprocess` which I find is the most reliable source of information to use in conjunction with the `hostname` field, if its on a location you can investigate and is an application that runs for long enough for you to check.

Answer (score 1):

Just as an FYI, the module_hash column in v$session has less to do with the app running it and more to do with the value passed to the DBMS_APPLICATION_INFO.SET_MODULE procedure ([ref](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14237/dynviews_2088.htm#REFRN30223)).  For instance, you can emulate any module_hash using SQL Plus to call this procedure, so I wouldn't count on your current approach being entirely foolproof.

I don't expect you to take my word for it though, so check [this AskTom post](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f%3Fp%3D100:11:::NO:RP:P11_QUESTION_ID:561622956788) in the comments section; Tom responds to Khandaker Anwar's *INTERESTING FINDINGS FROM V$SESSION TO PROTECT UNWANTED ACCESS TO DATABASE* comment countering this exact line of thought.

With that out of the way, if you still wish to emulate what is occurring in your Oracle environment, others (e.g. @Scott Hodgin and @Ste Bov) above have pointed out the **program_name** field in either the [sys.dm_exec_sessions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176013.aspx) DMV or [sys.sysprocesses](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179881.aspx) VIEW will provide similar identification as the module_hash field within Oracle as it can also be set to whatever you would like when establishing the connection to the database.

Frankly, I think this approach has too many ways around it and instead you should whitelist only those IPs or subnets that you want to allow connectivity from on your firewall and use Active Directory accounts or Groups to restrict access to only those parties who are allowed to connect to the database which echo's @Vladimir Oselsky's earlier comment.

Comment: Thanks, we will test it. The module hash is a means amongst others to allow or deny a connection. The IP Address and the UserName are also taken into account. 
The "simpler" approach will not fit in our environment, neither the requirement to allow users to connect only using "enterprise applications" (no Management Studio or SQL Developer tools for end users), unfortunately...

Comment: We've tested the information about Oracle you provided. We agree that the procedure will change module_name and module_hash values visible in v$session.
But, to run those commands, you will have to have already passed the logon trigger test. By the way, you are partially right: it doesn't seem possible to edit module value before connection. The module_hash is then the hash of the application name. Therefore, there is a hole in the model... (the same as for SQL Server)