# Profile Read/Write Traffic to SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, metrics

I am tasked with creating a new central database, with an all-new ERD / data schema, to replace a poorly designed database used by a range of applications.

To assist with both design and capacity planning, I want to profile all the read/write activity of the existing SQL Server database (preferably in production) over the space of a day or a month.  In particular I want:

1. An identifier of the application which initiated the read or write.  That strategy is already discussed in [this post](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/150131/mssql-uniquely-identify-an-application-connecting-sql-server), thus it is the next two points I mostly need help with.
2. A report of what "read-oriented" queries/sprocs where executed, in what frequency distribution, and approximately what amount of data was extracted (in KB or MB) for each query.  This desired report presumably would focus on "query hashes" for ad hoc queries, given that raw app/user queries are typically converted to an optimal form (and assigned a query hash) before being executed.
3. A report of what "write-oriented" actions were taken (DML or sprocs), along with frequency distribution and data quantities, as before.

As stated, I've already found a reasonable-ish answer to #1 above.  So it is mostly #2 and #3 that I need.

Incidentally, I am interested in answers that include network tooling that can help answer these questions.  In other words, if SQL Server is deficient at answering these questions, perhaps a network monitor can sleuth the answers?  I also would be curious if other, related cloud databases have a solution(s) for these questions.  For example, perhaps this is easier to answer if I'm instead using Azure SQL or Cosmos DB?

Comment: A network tool will not be able to detect reads vs. writes in the case of proc calls.

Answer (score 2):

[Profiler](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/sql-server-profiler/sql-server-profiler?view=sql-server-ver16) is the tool that'll answer most of your questions. It'll add overhead (like anything else) so I definitely wouldn't recommend running it for a month straight. Running it for a day or two *may* be ok depending on how busy your server is. It catches everything though, so you may want to add some filters too:

> Microsoft SQL Server Profiler is a graphical user interface to SQL Trace for monitoring an instance of the Database Engine or Analysis Services. You can capture and save data about each event to a file or table to analyze later. For example, you can monitor a production environment to see which stored procedures are affecting performance by executing too slowly. SQL Server Profiler is used for activities such as:
>
> - Stepping through problem queries to find the cause of the problem.
> - Finding and diagnosing slow-running queries.
> - Capturing the series of Transact-SQL statements that lead to a problem. The saved trace can then be used to replicate the problem on a test server where the problem can be diagnosed.
> - Monitoring the performance of SQL Server to tune workloads. For information about tuning the physical database design for database workloads, see Database Engine Tuning Advisor.
> - Correlating performance counters to diagnose problems.
>
> SQL Server Profiler also supports auditing the actions performed on instances of SQL Server.

Another option is [Extended Events](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/extended-events/quick-start-extended-events-in-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver16) which can be quite lighter of a solution than the Profiler when setup properly:

> Extended Events is a lightweight performance monitoring system that enables users to collect data needed to monitor and troubleshoot problems in SQL Server...By using Extended Events, you can see details about the inner operations of the SQL system and your application. When you create an Extended Events session, you tell the system:
>
> - Which occurrences you are interested in.
> - How you want the system to report the data to you.

Comment: "can be a little lighter" is a gross understatement. Running a Profiler trace to capture the all the batch and rpc completed events can crash a busy server.

Comment: @DanGuzman I guess when configured poorly either solution can be taxing though. But fair enough, updated my verbiage.